# How to delete a question with an open bounty

Tags: support, bounty, vote-to-delete

I've recently asked a question, concerning a problem with Visual Studio ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774437/how-to-configure-visual-studios-test-application)), so I asked how to configure everything in order to solve my problem.

In the meanwhile I've discovered that the issue was not caused by configuration, but by a version mismatch, which turns the question completely useless, hence I'd like to delete this question, but:
I had already put a bounty on that question, which is still open, and apparently questions with open bounties can't be deleted.

Is there a way to delete this question anyway? (It makes no sense drawing attention to a problem which can't be solved anyway)

Comment: It would need a mod to cancel the bounty but I'm a bit split if that should be done in this case. Your question is reasonable and well asked and I can see other people run into the same problem. Having an answer to that question seems valuable to me and future visitors. As your intent is to delete the question I would opt to leave the bounty to run out to see if it attracts a good answer. If that didn't happen after the bounty ended you can still delete it yourself. But I'm certainly interested what others have to say. I realize my advice is opposite what you ask for. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @rene: no need to feel sorry: the intention of stackoverflow website is to increase knowledge, while I asked for doing just the opposite. You're right: I'll wait and see if interesting answers might pop up and in case yes, I'll reward one with the bounty.

Comment: It seems like "Actually, it was a version mismatch, and here's how you can tell, and here's how you can fix it" *would* be a solid answer to the question.

Comment: @BenBarden Still a shame about the lost rep...

Comment: You should flag for mod